# Recursive number of divisors function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Does there exist a recursive function, or a recurrence relation, for the number-of-divisors function?

For example, something like this:

$\sigma_0(n) = \sigma_0(n-1) + \sigma_0(n-2)$

Comment: Often a recursive function means the same thing as a computable function. Clearly, the number of divisor function would be computable.

Comment: I doubt there will be one which you would find satisfying. For example, $n$ can have pretty arbitrary divisors with $n+1$ prime, and vice-versa (I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's multiplicative, so if $m,n$ are coprime, that is have gcd 1, then $\sigma(mn) = \sigma(m) * \sigma(n)$.

Comment: Could this be similar to the totient function which also has this property? Can I also say $\sigma(mn) = \sigma(m) * \sigma(n) * \frac{gcd(mn)}{\sigma(gcd(mn))}$? As per here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Other_formulae_involving_.CF.86

Comment: Khaled, have you tried it for small values of $m$ and $n$ to see whether it is plausible?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes and it didn't work (I tried 72 = 12*6), but I'm sure there must be a similar property since they are both multiplicative functions (I hope so anyway).

Answer (score 8):

I don't know about the number-of-divisors function, but Euler found a very nice recurrence for the sum-of-divisors function, which you can find [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.HO/0411587). A more recent treatment is [here](http://mathematicalspectacles.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/proving-eulers-recurrence-formula-for.html). See also John A. Ewell, Recurrences for the Sum of Divisors, Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 64, No. 2 (Jun., 1977), pp. 214-218.

The Euler recurrence is $$\sigma(n)=\sigma(n-1)+\sigma(n-2)-\sigma(n-5)-\sigma(n-7)+\sigma(n-12)+\sigma(n-15)-\dots$$ where the numbers $1,2,5,7,12,15,\dots$ are the "pentagonal numbers" $k(3k\pm1)/2$.

EDIT: The above formula isn't quite right when $n$ itself is a pentagonal number, in fact I think it's off by $n$. I'll try to find the time to edit in the precise correction (if someone else doesn't get there first).

EDIT2: [Here](https://euler.genepeer.com/eulers-pentagonal-number-theorem) is a link to replace the dead one. Also, one has to make the convention that $\sigma(n-n)=n$ to make the formula work when $n$ is a pentagonal number.

Comment: And this will not work for the number-of-divisors function?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: the "more recent treatmen" is a dead link.

Comment: @darij, yes, I noticed that yesterday, but wasn't able to find whatever it was that I linked to in 2012. But typing "pentagonal number formula" into the Internet should turn up no shortage of discussions of the formula.