# Is there a recurrence relation that describes the aliquot sum?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, divisor-sum

I am trying to understand the dynamics of the [aliquot sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliquot_sum).

I am wondering if a [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) exists?

For example, would this work:

- Let $s(x)$ be the aliquot sum for $x$
- Let $p$ be a prime
- If $x$ is $1$, then $s(x)=0$
- If $x$ is prime, then $s(x)=1$
- If $p \nmid x$, then $s(px) = s(x) + ps(x) + x$
- If $p | x$, then $s(px) = s(x) + x$

Thanks.

---

Edit: Made updates based on comments received by Mason.

Comment: Can you give an example? What's $s(25)$? And are we to assume $p$ is prime? Typically the aliquot sum is defined such that $s(1)=0$.

Comment: Yes, $p$ is prime.  I will add.  Thanks for calling that out.  $s(5) = 1$.  $s(25) = 1 + 5 = 6 = s(5) + 5s(5)$

Comment: Also you can probably get away with modifying Euler's recurrence formula for the divisor function. See [this](http://numberworld.blogspot.com/2013/09/sum-of-divisors-function-eulers.html)

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks very much.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  :-)

Comment: @LarryFreeman:  I suppose that you are interested in perfect numbers (odd ones, in particular).  To broaden your horizons, note that an odd perfect number $N$ given in the so-called *Eulerian form* $N = q^k n^2$ satisfies
$$D(q^k)D(n^2)=2s(q^k)s(n^2)$$
where $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ is the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $x$ and $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$ is the [aliquot sum](http://oeis.org/A001065) of $x$.

Comment: @LarryFreeman:  You can check out my questions where these concepts are discussed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f(x)+x=\sigma(x)=\sum_{d|x}d$. Then $f(x)$ is our aliquot function.

For coprime numbers $a,b$
Then $\sigma(a b)= \sigma(a)\sigma(b) $ so

$f(ab)+ab=(f(a)+a)(f(b)+b)$

This implies that

> $f(ab)= f(a)f(b)+bf(a)+af(b)$ for coprime $a,b$.

While we're talking about recurrence we should mention this amazing recurrence formula from Euler that can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189157/recursive-number-of-divisors-function).

Comment: and $p+q=2m$ so $2(p+q)=4m$ so they are alway different by a multiple of 4.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee. I think your comment must have got cut off.

Comment: nope just relating in another unsolved problem.  $$\varphi(n)+2(p+q) = \sigma_1(n)$$ with $p$ and $q$  prime is saying the difference ( admittedly in this case) is a multiple of 4 (see Goldbach).

Comment: Actually I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22721/is-there-a-formula-to-calculate-the-sum-of-all-proper-divisors-of-a-number/22744#22744) write up is a better resource. A little clearer.